# Is it possible to override class typings definition from libs in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I faced with problem in my react typescript app with overriding lib type definition for class.

```
import { RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom';

declare module 'react-router-dom' {
  interface AppRouterProps extends RouteProps {
    path: '/main' | '/home';
  }

  export class Route<T extends AppRouterProps = AppRouterProps> extends React.Component<T, any> {}
}
```

I want to override initial path definition for routing in my project, to prevent mistakes with routing. But it does not work. I can set any kind of path, and wont get any error.

```
 <Route path="/other" exact>
   <Home />
 </Route>
```

typingRoots in ts config set correct, overriding interfaces works properly.